# Jsoup Video Vk Parsing

Tags: java, android, jsoup, vk

I want to take the full link to the video.
I have link https://vk.com/video101958492_456239017

This is html page:
...

```
div class="videoplayer_media" style>
   video preload="metadata" class="videoplayer_media_provider" tabindex="-1" 
    aria-hidden="true" 
    src="https://cs543609.vkuservideo.net/u23043775/videos/c848bac57d.240.mp4?
       extra=JUrKvs_MKCeL0vDhGHfbh4xcCWR8UIFD0TAodiPOE7oXrrU1ePZ8-
       1WLDYUBQFWQtqD_BE-
       gFjjqISdWJpsUyidCIolHzeDa_o5zCvShsQdBVePR07Kn4_auRdbGs62UXFsSLeYYGks">
   /video>
/div>


private void videoVk() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = 
                Jsoup.connect("https://vk.com/video23043775_170249049")
                     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
                                 AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like 
                                 Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 
                                 Safari/535.21")
                     .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                     .maxBodySize(0)
                     .timeout(10000)
                     .get();

                Element video = 
                doc.select("meta[property=og:video]").first();

                Log.d("VIDEO_LINK", video.attr("content"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error:") 
                .append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                Log.d("ERROR", builder.toString());
            }

            if(getActivity() == null)
                return;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

It returns:
https://vk.com/video?act=get_swf&oid=5115837&vid=168139503&embed_hash=ba98594d0463bbfa

Should return https://cs543609.vkuservideo.net/u23043775/videos/c848bac57d.240.mp4?extra=JUrKvs_MKCeL0vDhGHfbh4xcCWR8UIFD0TAodiPOE7oXrrU1ePZ8-1WLDYUBQFWQtqD_BE-gFjjqISdWJpsUyidCIolHzeDa_o5zCvShsQdBVePR07Kn4_auRdbGs62UXFsSLeYYGks

I tried to find an element via a tag, a class, but it returns null.

```
doc.getElementsByTag("video");
doc.getElementsByClass("videoplayer_media_provider");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't make requests to VK site directly. There is API for this purposes: https://vk.com/dev/manuals
   This method is used for returning video:

   https://vk.com/dev/video.get?params[videos]=101958492_456239017&params[extended]=1&params[v]=5.73
2. VK doesn't return video file, only player code which you can embed.